# HTML form action with random url

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to post to random url in the action attribute of HTML form.
I can accomplish this with PHP like below,

```
<?php 
    $actions = array('option1.php', 'option2.php','option3.php'); 
    $which = rand(0,count($actions)-1); 
?> 
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $actions[$which]; ?>">
```

Is there any way that i can do this with just Javascript & HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for `submit` event on the form and prevent it afterwards change action to some random url and submit it from javascript. Should work.

```
<script>
    var myForm = document.getElementById('myform'),
    urls = ['url1.php', 'url2.php', 'url3.php'];

    myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        var randUrl = urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)];
        event.preventDefault();
        myForm.action = randUrl;
        myForm.submit();
    });
</script>
<form method="post" action="someurl.php" id="myform">
```